# beginAt, endAt using index instead of priority

Tags: firebase

Is there a way to use beginAt and endAt with index instead of priority so that I can do client-side pagination with it?

I assign .priority to non-null values for sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the second argument to startAt / endAt.

Note that priority always takes precedence when ordering messages, so you'll need the priority to be the same (ie null) for all items you want to sort by index.

You then just do this:

```
ref.startAt(null, indexToStartAt).endAt(null, indexToEndAt);
```

Comment: According to https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/startat.html, the syntax is startAt( [priority], [name] ). I do assign .priority (they're not null), but I'd also like to use pagination. Is that doable?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's the same syntax I used above. I don't understand your question. If what you want is to set a priority, and then have a separate query that orders them by name instead, that's not possible. If priorities are set, the items will always be ordered by priority. They'll only be ordered by name in cases where the priorities are the same (such as when they're all null).

Comment: So you're saying if I pass in null for priority in beginAt, it will simply disregard priority for the index? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you the priority for all of the elements is X, and you specify X as the first argument for startAt / endAt then it will disregard the priority and sort by name. (X could be null, or anything else)