# setWithPriority and searching

Tags: firebase

I have a firebase table called users: FirebaseURL + '/users/'. The naming scheme uses facebook id's like so:

```
users/
  |_____ facebook-01
                  |___ name
                  |___ email
  |_____ facebook-02
                  |___ name
                  |___ email
```

It contains information such as name, email, etc. I enabled an option for logged in users to create a username, which I want to set with priority so I can later search by it.

In code, I am setting the username like so:

```
new Firebase(URL + '/users/facebook-01')
    .child('username').setWithPriority(username, -1);
```

This correctly creates the username in the location, but I'm unable to search by it. I'm trying to get the correct person by using this:

```
new Firebase(URL + '/users/').startAt(username).endAt(username)
    .once('value', function(data) {
         console.log(data.val());
    });
```

From my understanding, and having read the blog https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html which describes SQL like queries, I should be able to use the priority to find the user by username (given that it's unique).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I think it may have to do with how I'm setting the username with "setWithPriority". Is there something I'm missing?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks SO!

Comment: possible duplicate of [beginAt, endAt using index instead of priority](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831565/beginat-endat-using-index-instead-of-priority)

Comment: Summary: use null for the priority and provide the id after that, as in `startAt(null, username).endAt(null, username)`.